# How to make two updates in one query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Having a table like this one:

```
+----+-------+
| id | Value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |  1000 |
|  2 |  1500 |
|  3 |  1250 |
|  4 |  2000 |
|  5 |  1800 |
+----+-------+
```

How can I update the column "value" while adding, for exame, x% for those who are less than 1600 and y % for those greater than this value in one query? Is it possible?

I can't update the lowest first because eventually some value may exceed the range of 1600. That way, when I have updated the largest , could do it in values that had already received the increase .

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement.  They're stop on match so you don't have to worry about double-updating the same record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
update table t
    set value = value * (case when value < 1600 then 1 + x
                              when value > 1600 the 1 + y
                              else 1
                         end);
```